# where to download file from selenium script in azure pipeline. And how to compare it with uploadingfile

Tags: c#, azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, continuous-integration

im writing a selenium webdriver C# script to upload a file on a then download this file. I am doing it locally and it  upoload file from my computer than download in my computer. But after continous integration when my code will run in azure pipeline build.(for upload file i put the files in a folder of project will upload from there)but on downloading where  my file will download. And how my code for compare with upload file will work??

Comment: How does your code download the files? Depending on the method, there could be a standard directory to which the files are saved. My guesses: `%temp%`, `%cwd%` or the system default download folder.

Comment: @jessehouwing it will download in Virtual machine?

Comment: It will be downloaded by whichever browser you're automating. If that runs on  a VM, then it will be downloaded there.

Comment: @jessehouwing if the downlaoding path is my local machine which i'm using while writing script. Then what will happen whem script will run on azure?

Comment: It will try whatever path in the script on the machien in Azure. What else would youy expect?